# What is wrong with my camera button delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a camera button in a collection view controller cell to take a picture, and output it to a UIImageView the size of the cell. Right now I'm getting a error with the delegate and I'm not quite sure what it wants me to do.

[image]

```
- (IBAction)cameraButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)]) {
        UIAlertView *cameraAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"There is no camera on this device which really defeats the purpose of this game. We suggest you get an iDevice with a camera." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cameraAlertView show];
    }else{
        //Show the Image Picker Controller Here
        UIImagePickerController * ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        ipc.allowsEditing = NO;
        //Set the Delegate
        ipc.delegate = self;

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that `self` does not conform to the UINavigationControllerDelegate and/or UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocols. [Implement those protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) on your class.

Comment: +1. You have to conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, which is often overlooked when using `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: The protocol thing is losing me. Do I just add "@protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate" in the .h file?

Comment: @RileyLloyd Take a look at the link in my answer. I think getting a solid understanding of what protocols are will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol in your header?